# How to associate a hyperlink to a complete webpage area?

Tags: html

What I want to implement is that every click on the area of a table cell (or of a table, or of the webpage itself) loads the specified url. The appearance of the text in the table cell (or ...) should not be influenced. Only html methods should be used.

Is this possible!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the cell in a div tag and then wrap the div in the link. 
Example: `<td><a href="link here" target="_blank"><div>Cell Text</div></a></td>`

You can then change the styling of a visited link in your css so that it does not change colors.

```
  a:visited 
    {
        text-decoration: none; 
        decoration: none; 
        Color:black;
    }
    a:hover 
    {
        text-decoration: none; 
        decoration: none; 
        Color:black;
    }
  a 
    {
        text-decoration: none; 
        decoration: none; 
        Color:black;
    }
```

Comment: Justin Allard: Thank you. But this last point is the point. If there is a complex css layout for the content of the table cell (or ...), how this layout can be preserved?

Comment: Are you looking for the URL to open up in a new tab? or are you looking for how to no change the link color? Please add a bit more detail or an example. I have edited my answer to show how to keep the text from changing colors.

Comment: Just a normal link (in my case to be opened in a new window, but ...)! As I said: The appearance of the text should not be influenced at all. As far as I see, the change of the text color unfortunately is not prevented by text-decoration: none etc. for a:link, a:visited etc.

Comment: I updated the css in my answer so that no changes are made to the text (Assuming you have black text). Also if you want the link to open the url in a new window make sure to add the target to your url as such <a href="link here" target="_blank">

Comment: As I said: The layout of text in the table cell (or ...) can be complex (words in different colors etc.), so Color:black is not a solution.